# Fail to instal profile tool qgis plugin

Tags: qgis

I´ve just tried to install "Profile tool" plugin on my QGIS version (2.14) but the following error message appeared:

"The plugin is broken. Python says: No module named PyQt.QtCore".

Does anybody any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7 (64 bits). Once I have installed the plugin the followin error message appears: "The plugin seems to be invalid or have unfulfilled dependences. It has been installed, but can´t be loaded. Here is the error message below: the plugin is broken. Python said: No module named PyQt.QtCore". Thanks.